# bashrc alias argument add a white space

Tags: bash, arguments, alias

I want to set an alias in bashrc to read an argument and output it to screen.

```
alias myecho='echo 123'
```

If I do

```
$> myecho
```

I can get the right result.

```
123
```

But if I put an argument to the alias

```
alias myecho2="echo 123.$1"
```

and I do

```
$> myecho2 555
```

I will get a white space in front of the parameter I enter.

```
123 .555
```

What shall I do to get rid of the white space?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases don't have arguments. `$1` is empty in this context.

`echo 123.$1` is in fact `echo 123.` and only the `myecho2` part of the command is expanded to `echo123.`. The space that follows and `555` are not changed.

You can use a function to achieve the desired behaviour:

```
function myecho3() {
    echo 123.$1          # The quotes are not needed
}
myecho3 555

# Displays
# 123.555
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
alias myecho2="printf '123.%s\n'"
```

Then `myecho foo` expands to `printf '123.%s\n' foo` which does what you want.